# Convert char array into double

Tags: c, printf, double, fgets, atof

I have tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *txt1;
char tam[13];
char tam1[13];
char tam2[13];

txt1 = fopen("C:/Users/Hugo/Documents/C/in2.txt","r");
if(txt1 == NULL)
{
    printf("No se puede leer el archivo");
    return 0;
}
fgets(tam1,sizeof(tam1), txt1);
double c = atof(tam1);
printf("%f",c);
```

when I debug: `tam1` is "3.1415926535" But it prints this:

> 0.000000

Comment: Did you mean to `printf` `tam1`, or `c`?

Comment: Try `fscanf(txt1, "%lf", &c)` instead.

Comment: @nneonneo it didn't work

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong. Your code looks basically right, unless your file contains some bizarre characters or something.

Comment: yeah it was something like that.. i fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *txt1;
        char tam[13];
        char tam1[13];
        char tam2[13];
        txt1 = fopen("99.c","r");
        if(txt1 == NULL)
        {
                printf("No se puede leer el archivo");
                return 0;
        }
        fgets(tam1,sizeof(tam1), txt1);
        double c = atof(tam1);
        printf("%f",c);// change from c
}

o/p:
rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 
3.141593rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ vi 4.c
```

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: for me its working fine o/p is as expected.

Comment: now my problem is i need to get 0.00000056 but it convert it as 5.6

Comment: double c = atof(tam1);
        printf("%.8f",c);    o/p-->rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$ ./a.out 
0.00000056rabi@rabi-VirtualBox:~/rabi/c$